# Android: How can I get the Pitch from the audio file created by mediaRecorder?

Tags: android, audio

I used the Class MediaRecorder to record a ".wav" files.

I can find the amplitude by getMaxAmplitude().

But How can I find the Pitch or frequency of the audio file? There are not much function provided in this class. Please help.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11844914/get-the-frequency-of-an-audio-file-in-every-1-4-seconds-in-android